# Who should I contact to remove an old boiler from my basement?

Tags: boiler, disposal

I had a boiler fire. When I replaced the boiler, I kept the old one around for insurance purposes. Now it's time to get rid of it.

It's got a good bit of steel in it, and still has a couple of steel
steam pipes attached. I wonder if it has any salvage value. 
Maybe enough for somebody to come haul it away for "free". Regardless -- win, lose, or draw - it's gotta go.

Who should I be calling to do this, and what should I know going in?

---

- It's sitting by the bulkhead. With the right equipment and a couple of guys, it shouldn't be too hard to get out.
- Boiler was mfd. in 1993, so asbestos free. It's cracked, unusable.

---

**Epilogue:** Found free removal by chance. See answer below.

Comment: Where is it?  As in what country?

Comment: Every boiler I have seen removed was broken apart before removal, then scrapped by the plumber.
I doubt it's worth much so I doubt you'll get it removed for free. If you break it up yourself you can probably save a few bucks.

Comment: @wallyk USA! USA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had my old boiler hauled away free. I found the guy by happening upon his truck,  which said "FREE METAL REMOVAL" on the side, with a phone number. Great guy. My wife saw a different, but similar truck the week before.

It's not foolproof, but in this case, serendipity provided.

Answer (score 3):

Look for a scrap metal dealer in [your area](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=scrap%20metal%20recycling&hl=en&sll=45.543408,-122.654422&sspn=0.489079,1.056747&hq=scrap%20metal%20recycling&hnear=Massachusetts&geocode=FSsVhwIdW8q--w&t=m&z=9).

If you deliver the steel parts to the recycler, you ought to get at least $400 per tonne (which is $440 per U.S. ton or $0.22 per pound).  See [this](http://www.scrapregister.com/scrap-prices/united-states/260).

Comment: Those were the days... Last I checked it was under $200.